# unable to load local image in superset dashboard

Tags: apache-superset

i am trying to load a local image from D drive into my superset dashboard using markdown. but for some reason my default path is being appended to the url on which superset is running.

the path when i inspect the image in console window->

```
http://localhost:5000/superset/dashboard/3/D:\covid19-img.jpg
```

here is the code->

```
<img style="width:800px; height:280px;" src="D:\covid19-img.jpg">
```

can somenone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution. just like angular, images need to be kept in a certain folder. in your virtual environment find this path->

```
\venv\Lib\site-packages\superset\static
```

paste your image here. and then in markdown, put `img src` as

```
/static/{your image here}.{image extension}
```

this will load the local image in dashboard and then you will be able to download the dashboard as an image as well.